# conditional formatting with column name

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

I had a litle problem. I've got a conditional formatting on a column (A) who look at an other one (B).

On the past I use VBA to create my conditional formatting with dat code:

```
    Range("I3:I99").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=W1=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

And dat work but my board are not fix and new column can arrived between.

I decide to rename "W" Column "OPI"
And change my code like this:

```
    Range("I3:I99").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OPI1=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

But dat didn't work. And Don't had more idea how write it???

Thanks to helping me and have a nice day

Comment: Please, make "OPI" a named range and it should work.

Comment: U mean write dim OPI as range?

Comment: I try it ... but even if dat's Don't carsh all my reference becone red even if cells are not = 0

Comment: It shouldn't. Excel adapt the named ranges in case of rows/columns insertions/deletions... A named range can be simple obtained by selecting the range and then go to the left side of the formula bar (to the Name Box), select the cell address, replace it with a string name (**OPI** in your case) **and press Enter**.

Comment: I ask my self if he try to go on column OPI like u can have ,(ZZ,AAA,AAB,AAC,...)?

Comment: I try to use cells sélections but he write =$W$1=0 even if my column are rename "OPI"

Comment: How did you renamed the column as "OPI"?

Comment: click on "w" on go on formulas' windowns "set a name"

Comment: If you go to the left formula bar side, click on Name Box, type OPI and press Enter, is the column W:W selected?

Comment: Yes i select it. and when i selct the column she was named Opi on the left formula bar side

Comment: I Don't understand why my column was name "OPI" but first cell on the column = "W1"

Comment: It was not been updated, being considered an error. It needs to extract a Cell range from the named one. Try clearing the format and use my answer code, please. Or, just run the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub TestValidationNamedRange()
 With Range("I3:I99")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & Range("OPI").cells(3).Address(0, 0) & "=0"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Antoine Dargouge: Glad that I (finally) could help!